# AES128 decryption in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have received only a key and a value which is encrypted using AES.  I now need to decrypt this and retrieve the value from it.  However all samples i found online are using other properties to decrypt (salt, IV, ...)

I have seen this website online  http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ and I am able to 'decrypt' it as a binary file.

however doing this in c# seems not to work for me.

Can anyone provide me a simple way of decrypting AES_128 in c# with only the encrypted value and a key?

Edit

1. Retrieve the IV from the key:

   ```
   Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DecryptionConstants.AES_KEY);
   using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
   {
       // Convert Key to bytes and pass into AES
       aesAlg.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(DecryptionConstants.AES_KEY);
       IV = new byte[aesAlg.BlockSize / 8];

       var hexKey = BitConverter.ToString(IV);
       IV = StringToByteArray("a2 26 cb 78 e2 cb 26 cb e7 c7 f0 bc c7 7b bd 9d");

   }
   ```
2. Decrypt

   ```
   byte[] EncryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);

   //Setup the AES provider for decrypting.            
   AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider
   {
       Key = Key,
       IV = this.IV,
       BlockSize = 128,
       KeySize = 256,
       Padding = PaddingMode.None,
       Mode = CipherMode.CBC,                
   };

   var cryptoTransform = aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(aesProvider.Key, aesProvider.IV);

   var DecryptedBytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(EncryptedBytes, 8, EncryptedBytes.Length-8);
   ```

This results in a byte array which in no way can be brought back to the string i have put in.

Comment: Looking at the link you sent in the question, the IV is probably the first 16 bytes of your data block. Also please elaborate what have you tried already and so some code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Patrick Site you're using has many options of encryption and decryption. Which options did you use? Have you tried to replicate these options in the code that you copied from somewhere?

Comment: I have used these options i presume.  AES Function and CBC mode.  Other options i cannot set.  Input automatically switches to HEX, but i cannot set that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

With your data you should guess the IV, likely 16 zeros or the first 16 bytes of data, and the CipherMode, ECB, CBC or so.

This is a small function that I use to encrypt/decrypt:

```
    public static byte[] EncryptAES(byte[] message, byte[] key, bool doEncryption)
    {
        try
        {
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = new byte[16];
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            ICryptoTransform cipher;

            if (doEncryption == true)
                cipher = aes.CreateEncryptor();
            else
                cipher = aes.CreateDecryptor();

            return cipher.TransformFinalBlock(message, 0, message.Length);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I simply transform my message I got an error that my byte array is not the right size (264) instead of (256)

Comment: @Patrick the message must be a multiple of the block size (16 bytes). Try to pad with zeros